# Receiving Type Error 1009, while trying to play a MC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Though I once knew Flash, I haven't kept up with it over the last decade and am now very out of date.

My goal with this is to create a simple animation that is progressed by each keystroke. The words are predetermined so I created them as a text on my stage. I then keyed out a mask to reveal each letter. Each keystroke moves the animation along to a label defined by an array. At the end of the array, at "wrong", I'm trying to have a movie clip play once then stop, the mc is referred to as mc_Shake.

Currently I can't get the mc to play, and receive the error 1009. If I do get the movie clip to play entire animation just plays on loop.

The exact error message I receive is:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Al_fla::MainTimeline/ResetScene()

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;


stop();

var Password:Array = ["Start","a","n","n_2","e","m","u","r","r_2","y", "Wrong"]
var nextLetter:String;
var inc:int = 1;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, clickNextSection);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, ResetScene);

function clickNextSection(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (inc <= 9)
    {
        nextLetter = String(Password[inc]);
        gotoAndStop(nextLetter);
        trace("Button Works");
        inc++;

    }
    else
    {
        trace("greater then 12");
        trace("No Works");
        inc++;
    }

}

function ResetScene(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (inc >= 10)
    {
        mc_Shake.play();
        trace("Button Works");
        inc++;

    }
    else
    {
        trace("Under11");
        trace("No Works");

}

}
```

Comment: Which line gives you 1009 error?  **mc_Shade.play()**?  can you post your .fla? that would be easiest for troubleshooting.  Can you reword your last sentence (*or if I do it to play I compromises the rest of the animation and it plays through on a loop.*), I don't quite undestand.   ----- Most likely you don't have an instance name on your mc_Shake on whatever frame runs that code

Comment: I double checked, and the instance is named correctly.  I also edited my post to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer then so others who view this question can see what resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because in the current scope, there is no object called/referenced `mc_Shake`

eg. Wherever the playhead is when this condition is met:

```
if (inc >= 10){
    mc_Shake.play();
    ...
```

This is usually the result of having your instance name set appropriately on the first frame, but then later in your timeline having keyframes or blank keyframes that make `mc_Shake` not available or unloaded.

Check all your keyframes in your timeline, and make sure you have a instance of your object in question on the stage at all times, and with an instance name of `mc_Shake`.